# Mysql range select

Tags: mysql

I have a small problem with selecting some results from the database.
The results I'm trying to select have a `start_date` and `end_date` which store the full date. My client wants a feature on his site to filter all of the records by month.

Here are a couple of example records:

```
id  start_date  end_date
01  01.03.13    20.05.13
02  12.04.13    30.06.13
03  24.05.13    29.07.13
04  10.05.13    30.05.13  
05  19.06.13    13.08.13
06  03.07.13    18.09.13
```

If the month is `05`, then records `id 01-04` should be displayed.

Any ideas how this would be done with MySQL?

Comment: Are you filtering by start_date? end_date? both?

Comment: At this moment I'm not filtering anything - I'm trying to figure out how to get those records. I was thinking of using `start_date >= MONTH AND end_date <= MONTH` but that won't work in this case.

Comment: Are you really storing the dates as strings, instead of DATE type?

Comment: No, I'm storing them as DATE type :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This query will return all events whose range includes May 2013.

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE start_date < '2013-06-01'
AND end_date >= '2013-05-01'
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
select id from yourTable where month(start_date) == 5 or month(end_date)==5
```

Comment: This won't find row 02. It starts in April and ends in June.